# SQL Query: JOIN Three tables thenNot showing the results after joining the 3rd table

Tags: sql, zoho

I have three tables as follows:

LoanMaster Table

```
LoanID  BranchName  DisbursementDate  DisbursementAmount
12345   H1          01-01-18          25000
12346   A1          05-01-18          20000
12347   M1          06-02-18          16000
```

Collection Table

```
LoanID  TransactionDate Amount
12345   05-02-18        500
12346   06-02-18        600
```

OverdueCollection Table

```
LoanID  TransactionDate Amount
12345   05-02-18    200
12346   07-02-18    300
```

Required Output

```
LoanID  BranchName  TransactionDate Collection Amount   Overdue Amount  
12345   H1          05-02-18        500                 200 
12346   A1          06-02-18        600                 NULL    
12346   A1          07-02-18        NULL                300 
12347   M1          NULL            NULL                NULL
```

i have applied the following two queries to get the two tables join

"QRY_Test2":

```
SELECT   c.LoanID LoanID, date(c.TransactionDate) TransDate, (c.Amount) Amt,
         d.Amount = NULL FROM  Collection c 
UNION
SELECT  d.LoanID LoanID, date(d.TransactionDate) TransDate, c.Amount = NULL,
         (d.Amount) as Amt FROM  Overdue Amount d
```

and then group by to get the unique results, Named finalTable:

```
SELECT LoanID, TransDate, sum("Amount"), sum("Amt") FROM  "QRY_Test2"
GROUP BY LoanID, TransDate
```

then i get the following result:

```
LoanID  TransactionDate Collection Amount   Overdue Amount  
12345   05-02-18        500                 200 
12346   06-02-18        600                 NULL    
12346   07-02-18        NULL                300
```

Then if i apply the left join with LoanMaster, I get no results:

```
Select LoanID, BranchName, TransactionDate, CollectionAmount, OverdueAmount from LoanMaster lm LEFT JOIN on FinalTable f lm.LoanID = f.loanid
```

Just wanted to understand what is the issue and i need the above mentioned required output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge here is in generating a table which contains the collection and overdue amounts, for a given day and loan, in a single record.  We can take a union of the `Collection` and `OverdueCollection` tables, and then pivot by loan and date.  Then, just left join the loan master table to this subquery.

```
SELECT
    lm.LoanID,
    lm.BranchName,
    t.TransactionDate,
    t.CollectionAmount,
    t.OverdueAmount
FROM LoanMaster lm
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT LoanID, TransactionDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN Amount END) AS CollectionAmount,
        MAX(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN Amount END) AS OverdueAmount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT LoanID, TransactionDate, Amount, 1 AS type
        FROM Collection
        UNION ALL
        SELECT LoanID, TransactionDate, Amount, 2
        FROM OverdueCollection
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        LoanID, TransactionDate
) t
    ON lm.LoanID = t.LoanID;
```

Comment: The idealogy and solution is good and working fine. Thanks for the help. I learnt CASE statement too as i am a beginner to write the complex queries.